# Is it possible to give OP's option of moving SO related topics from MSE to MSO?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I can't feel any difference between meta stack exchange and meta stackoverflow, I (and I think many others too) had used to use MSE as would it be MSO, So now, as there is a specific MSO site, wouldn't it be wise, to give at least the option of moving the own content from MSE to MSO?

Or am I even the only one who abused the purpose of MSE as would it be MSO?

Comment: We just took **great pains** to split them and now you're asking us to merge them back together?

Comment: @BoltClock I'm not aksing for merging the purposes of the sites, I'm asking for merging the posted content. As my MSE account only contains SO related topics, wouldn't it be wity to give me the posibility to move the SO related stuff to MSO? And what I'm saying is, I would bet I'm not the only one who could help this way splitting already exisiting content.

Comment: Related: [Are meta site questions linked to each other?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/198530) (and [Searching in any meta site should include results from Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230105))

Comment: If you're not asking for a merge, but are instead requesting the move of SO specific content to MSO, you might want to update your title to reflect that.

Comment: @Bart You'r right, I probably used a misleading title.

Comment: @Zaibis sounds like more trouble than it is worth since this is just a temporarily issue related to the split.  If the question is very old, then it is probably better just to repost it on MSO and link to the MSE post.  If it is a newer post and much of the discussion is still relevant and the post is relevant to Stack Overflow only, then it should be easily migrated by flagging and asking the MSE Mods (aka the SE Community Team) to move it and explain why it belongs on MSO

Comment: I wasn't confused before, but now I am.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It's already possible: Flag the question

To move a stack *overflow* specific question from MSE to MSO - just flag it for moderator attention with an appropriate message:

[image: Flag other: This question is SO specific - please migrate to MSO]